# How to implement a Docker-based PostgreSQL database with Quarkus to emulate the production setup where the PostgreSQL connection will be external?

Tags: postgresql, docker, gradle, quarkus

I’m trying to implement a Docker-based PostgreSQL database with Quarkus to emulate the production setup where the PostgreSQL connection will be external. The docker cleanup task does not execute when I stop quarkusDev from Intellij.

Below is the gradle task I created:

```
tasks.register('devMode', Task) {
    dependsOn quarkusDev
    finalizedBy stopPostgres
}
```

I believe there should be an easier way to achieve my end goal, which is to have a simulated run of a PostgreSQL instance outside the quarkusDev and Docker instance stop once the task is completed. Does anyone know of any possible solutions to this problem?

**Please do not suggest dev services**, since I have some requirements which does not allow me to use dev-services.

**Please do not suggest docker-compose gradle plugin**, since I do not have docker-compose on my enterprise machine.

I want to use it with the quarkusDev Gradle task. I’ve tried the following code:

```
tasks.register('startPostgres', Exec) {
    ext.POSTGRES_USER = 'postgres'
    ext.POSTGRES_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxx'
    ext.POSTGRES_DB = 'postgres'
    ext.POSTGRES_EXPOSED_PORT = new ServerSocket(0).withCloseable { it.localPort }
    ext.CONTAINER_NAME = "postgres-${POSTGRES_EXPOSED_PORT}"
    commandLine 'docker', 'run', '-d', '--name', "${CONTAINER_NAME}", '-p', "${POSTGRES_EXPOSED_PORT}:5432", '-e', 'POSTGRES_USER=' + "${POSTGRES_USER}", '-e', 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=' + "${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}", '-e', 'POSTGRES_DB=' + "${POSTGRES_DB}", 'postgres:16.1'
}
quarkusDev.dependsOn startPostgres

tasks.register('stopPostgres', Exec) {
    dependsOn startPostgres
    commandLine 'docker', 'stop', "${startPostgres.CONTAINER_NAME}"
}

tasks.register('devMode', Task) {
    dependsOn quarkusDev
    finalizedBy stopPostgres
}
```

The startPostgres task runs before quarkusDev, but the stopPostgres task does not run when I stop the Gradle run from IntelliJ. I’ve searched online and found out that it has something to do with tasks running in the foreground/background.